# Run Angular App on multiple Dynamic Subdomains

Tags: angular, subdomain, multi-tenant, aws-amplify

**I want to run the angular app on multiple dynamically generated subdomains.**
Its multi-tenants system
E.g:
Domain (web.com)
Subdomain
-User1.web.com -User2.web.com (when a user registered we need to make the unique subdomain related to his name)

What's the most suitable and good approach
Right now it's deployed in Aws amplify (amplify not support domain wildcard option)

But **we can create a domain using AWS SDK**. (But maybe limitations of only 50 subdomains when creating programmatically)

**One thing could be using s3 + cloud front (wildcard CNAME) is it good?**

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at least for me, I am using **vercel** instead of aws-amplify
because **vercel** supports subdomain wild card.

But you need to change the name server of your domain provider with the **vercel** name server to fully support subdomain wild card.

More about in this [link](https://vercel.com/blog/wildcard-domains)

<sub>Note: Answer provided by OP on question section</sub>